# Linux - How to use CAPS LOCK as both a SHIFT and BACKSPACE?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap

I want to be able to use the `caps lock` key on my keyboard as a `shift key` when I am holding it down and as a `backspace` when I release the key (given that I didn't press any other keys in that interval). I prefer a native solution (such as `xmodmap`), but I'm not sure if it is possible to regulate `KEYUP` and `KEYDOWN` presses using just the basic system tools.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any native ways to do that but [xcape](https://github.com/alols/xcape) dose what you want:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Remap the key to it's default behavior
# assuming `keycode 66` is your `caps lock` 
# check using `xmodmap -pke | grep Caps_Lock`
xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Shift_L Shift_L Shift_L Shift_L Shift_L Shift_L'

# if you remaped your standard backspace key (skip  
# this line if you didn't)  it will no longer be 
# available in the keymap but xcape needs it to be there. 
# To fix this, pick a keycode that's
# not on your physical keyboard (find one using 
# `xmodmap -pke`) and remap it to `BackSpace`. I will 
# assume that `keycode 248` is unused:
xmodmap -e 'keycode 248 = BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace BackSpace '

# kill `xcape` if it's already running so you don't
# get two competing instances
pidof xcape | xargs kill -1

# actually start xcape
xcape -e 'Shift_L=BackSpace'
```

Put this in a script and run it on startup (after testing of course).

Potential issues:

- Unfortunately, this isn't 100% reliable (at least on my system) Sometimes it will just randomly stop working. Rerunning the script reliably fixes this though. I setup a keyboard shortcut (that's unaffected by any keyboard remappings) to run the script, so having to rerun once in a while isn't too painful.
- This will add the *Backspace on release* behavior to all `Shift_L` keys. If there are any (find out using `xmodmap -pke | grep Shift_L`) you may want to remap those to `Shift_R`.
- There are applications that that don't seem to be affected by this. Those are really rare though. The only one I encountered is the Signal messenger. There might also be some video games that that come with their own build in input system and therefor cut out any system level modifications.

P.S. I'm using this to map both `control` and `escape` to my `cabslock` key. As a `vim` and `kakoune` user I find this very useful.

P.P.S. sorry if this answer comes very late, but this was my top result on google so even if this isn't useful to the OP anymore, others might still find it helpful.